# Avoid creating menu items for every node

Tags: 7, routes

I have defined a content type and unchecked every menu item under Menu settings -> Available menu. The problem is that every time i add a new node for the content type, Drupal creates a new menu item in the primary menu. 
How can i avoid it?

Comment: This can't be true :) Please provide screen-shots of node/add form and also content type configuration form